# How to make a cleaner code that counts multiple button clicks using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a counter for button clicks and it's working fine, but I would like to ask how I can make it cleaner and less repetitive and still do the same function?

To give a perspective, I'm using this to track usage of hundreds of buttons, therefore the code can look really messy if I stick to use my current script.

How would I go about and make this simpler and cleaner?

```js
function clickCounter1() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount1) {
      localStorage.clickcount1 = Number(localStorage.clickcount1) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount1 = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "Btn 1: " + localStorage.clickcount1;
  }
}

function clickCounter2() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount2) {
      localStorage.clickcount2 = Number(localStorage.clickcount2) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount2 = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Btn 2: " + localStorage.clickcount2;
  }
}

function clickCounter3() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount3) {
      localStorage.clickcount3 = Number(localStorage.clickcount3) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount3 = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = "Btn 3: " + localStorage.clickcount3;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickCounter1()" type="button">Btn 1</button>
<button onclick="clickCounter2()" type="button">Btn 2</button>
<button onclick="clickCounter3()" type="button">Btn 3</button>

<br>

<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

Important functions are just two:

1. Count the clicks for each button
2. Store in local storage

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [You're meant to use `getItem` and `setItem` with `window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage). I don't believe the Storage API specification allows custom properties (like `clickcount2`) to be persisted... if it _does_ cause data to be persisted beyond a full page reload then colour me surprised...

Comment: Thank you, I'm a newbie and just found the original script from a website, and it seems to work and store the data to localStorage..

Comment: " and it seems to work and store the data to localStorage" - But does it work between page-loads? (as in, completely separate browser windows/instances?)

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, but it does store it after page refresh, browser and pc restart. It doesn't however work if I start browsing in incognito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```js
function clickCounter(num) {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.getItem(`clickcount${num}`)) {
            localStorage.setItem(`clickcount${num}`, Number(localStorage.getItem(`clickcount${num}`)) + 1);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem(`clickcount${num}`, 1);
        }
        document.getElementById(`result${num}`).innerHTML = `Btn ${num}: ` + localStorage.getItem(`clickcount${num}`);
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickCounter(1)" type="button">Btn 1</button>
<button onclick="clickCounter(2)" type="button">Btn 2</button>
<button onclick="clickCounter(3)" type="button">Btn 3</button>
<br>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

You can do it even shorter like this:

```
function clickCounter(num) {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        let storedItem = localStorage.getItem(`clickcount${num}`);
        storedItem ? localStorage.setItem(`clickcount${num}`, Number(storedItem) + 1) : localStorage.setItem(`clickcount${num}`, 1);
        document.getElementById(`result${num}`).innerHTML = `Btn ${num}: ${storedItem}`;
    }
}
```

**Update in case you want to show buttons names**
you can simply do this:

```
<button onclick="clickCounter(this, 1)" type="button" data-name="First">Btn 1</button>
<button onclick="clickCounter(this, 2)" type="button" data-name="Second">Btn 2</button>
<button onclick="clickCounter(this, 3)" type="button" data-name="Third">Btn 3</button>
<br>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

Your javascript should looks like this:

```
function clickCounter(btn, num) {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        let storedItem = localStorage.getItem(`clickcount${num}`),
            btnName = $(btn).attr('data-name');
        storedItem ? localStorage.setItem(`clickcount${num}`, Number(storedItem) + 1) : localStorage.setItem(`clickcount${num}`, 1);
        document.getElementById(`result${num}`).innerHTML = `${btnName}: ${storedItem}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Just one question please if it's ok, how can I change the `Btn 1:` in `"Btn 1: " + localStorage` to change its "name" according to each button? It can probably get the button name for now or maybe use an attribute `name=""`?

Comment: check out the updated solution @ixcode

Comment: I really like this solution... but is there a way to change the way it gives name to a button? That way I can easily identify which button is which (in my tool they don't just use numbers in their names, but also some words). Can we maybe use `id` or `name` attribute for the output?

Comment: @ixcode check out the updated version

Comment: the updated version doesn't seem to work for me, although I get the idea and might be able to get it to work with some tweaking... thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below approach to do so. By creating a single function `clickCounter()` and passing it the button's Id/name. It will work the same.

**Working code:**

```js
function clickCounter(btnId) {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage[btnId]) {
      localStorage[btnId] = Number(localStorage[btnId]) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage[btnId] = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result1").textContent = "Btn 1: " + localStorage[btnId];
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickCounter('clickcount1')" type="button">Click me!</button>
<button onclick="clickCounter('clickcount2')" type="button">Click me!</button>
<button onclick="clickCounter('clickcount3')" type="button">Click me!</button>

<br>

<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding to my query. Just some questions please, the code above now only outputs the result on at a time in `result1` div instead of displaying all at the same time. Also, can you please tell me how to change the output text so that `Btn 1` will have `Btn 1: + localStorage` and it should change for the other buttons.. again, thank you kindly!

Comment: You should be using `.textContent`, not `innerHTML`, to prevent XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks @Dai, I updated my answer to with your correction

Answer (score 1):

there are several things to say about the code you show us.

1. Use localStorage.setItem() and localStorage.getItem() to manipulate
   data on the local storage (the API is done like it)
2. Prefer to register events on DOM element in the javascript code, not directly in the HTML code (it is a best practise)

Here is an example of implementation I did and it works:

```
<button type="button" id="btn1">Btn 1</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2">Btn 2</button>
<button type="button" id="btn3">Btn 3</button>

<br>

<div id="resultbtn1"></div>
<div id="resultbtn2"></div>
<div id="resultbtn3"></div>
```

---

```
function handleClickCounter(id) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.getItem(id)) {
            localStorage.setItem(id, Number(localStorage.getItem(id)) + 1);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem(id, 1);
        }
        document.getElementById("result"+id).textContent = "Btn " + id + ": " + localStorage.getItem(id);
    }
}


const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");    // change by more specific selector if needed

for (const button of buttons) {
    console.log(button.id)
    button.addEventListener("click", () => handleClickCounter(button.id));
}
```

Of course this code can be improved. Good luck and feel free to ask clarification :)

Comment: Hi thank you for responding to my query. I like that it uses `id` to name the buttons in the output.. however it doesn't seem to work when I try running it?

Comment: Oh have you write the "defer" attribute on the script tag on your html?
<script src="script/script.js" defer></script>

Comment: In addition I forgot to remove the "console.log(button.id)" in the for loop, feel free to remove it ;)